# GSON not returning key name, only value (Java)

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to format some String data to JSON using the GSON api, as shown in my returnJson() method:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class HUKD {
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;
    @SerializedName("Deal URL")    
    public String dealUrl;
    @SerializedName("Product URL")    
    public String productUrl;
    @SerializedName("Image URL")        
    public String imgUrl;
    @SerializedName("Description")        
    public String description; 
    @SerializedName("Temperature")        
    public String temperature;
    @SerializedName("EAN")
    public String ean;
    @SerializedName("Price")
    public String price;
    @SerializedName("Amazon Price")
    public String amazonPrice;
    @SerializedName("Price Difference")
    public String priceDifference;
    @SerializedName("Amazon URL")
    public String amazonUrl;

    public HUKD(String title, String dealUrl, String productUrl, String imgUrl, String description, String temperature, String ean, String price, String amazonPrice, String priceDifference, String amazonUrl) {
        this.title = title;
        this.dealUrl = dealUrl;
        this.productUrl = productUrl;
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        this.description = description;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.ean = ean;
        this.price = price;
        this.amazonPrice = amazonPrice;
        this.priceDifference = priceDifference;
        this.amazonUrl = amazonUrl;
    }

public String returnJson(){
    System.out.println("********TESTING OBJECTS*************");
    String[] jsonBuilder = new String []{title, dealUrl, productUrl, imgUrl, description, temperature, ean, price, amazonPrice, priceDifference, amazonUrl};
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
    String json = gson.toJson(jsonBuilder );
    return json;
}
```

However, GSON will only return the value, not the key:

```
[
  "Philips shm3560/10 on ear headphones Â£8.99 from Argos",
  "http://www.hotukdeals.com/deals/philips-shm3560-10-headphones-8-99-from-argos-2390246?aui\u003d1063",
  "http://www.hotukdeals.com/visit?m\u003d5\u0026q\u003d2390246",
  "http://static.hotukdeals.com/images/threads/2390246_1.jpg",
  "Argos cat no- 108/7390\nhttp://www.argos.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchMobile?storeId\u003d10151\u0026catalogId\u003d25051\u0026langId\u003d110\u0026searchTerm\u003d108%2F7390",
  "171°",
  "8712581626211",
  "£8.99",
  "£12.59",
  "Argos is cheaper than Amazon by £3.60",
  "http://www.amazon.co.uk/Philips-SHM3560-10-Pc-headset-Shm3560/dp/B008FSE6EU%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAILN2TPM667MBMJAQ%26tag%3Dgithubcomthis-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB008FSE6EU"
]
```

I've tried to get around this by adding the SerializedName annotation as suggested in the "JSON Field Naming Support" section of the API documentation [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), but I'm still not having any luck. Ideally, I'd like the JSON formatted like so:

```
"title":"Philips shm3560/10 on ear headphones Â£8.99 from Argos"
```

(and so on...), i.e. with the key name printed as specified in the @SerializedName annotation in the field declaration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not serializing your object, but array of Strings so you see proper result of this serialization. If you want to serialize your object you must use something like this:

```
public String returnJson(){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
    String json = gson.toJson(this);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I realised the mistake now! the returnJson method was originally in another class, and I'd forgotten to remove the array out. This solution works perfectly - thanks! (will accept once it allows me to)